# Concating a prefix to each element in an array in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a field in a Snowflake table which contains an array of strings (e.g. `["val1","val2","val3"]`).

I want to write a query which returns the array with a prefix added to each of the elements (e.g. `["pre:val1","pre:val2","pre:val3"]`).

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This case is "open and close".

Open the array , add bit , close array.

```
select array_agg(concat('pre',f.value) )   from table(flatten(input=> parse_json( '["val1","val2","val3"] '))) f;
```

[image]